# How to check delayed/scheduled messages in RabbitMQ's Mnesia

Tags: java, rabbitmq, mnesia

I was checking for some alternatives for [Quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Though this is not a complete replacement, I was trying out [RabbitMQ Delayed Messages Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) (suits for my use-case).

I was able to get the scheduling work but I was not to view the messages which are delayed(which are stored in `Mnesia`).

Is there a way to check the messages and/or number of messages in `Mnesia`?

**Edit** : I inferred that the messages are stored in `Mnesia` from the comment from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/).

Comment: The messages are not stored in MNESIA

Comment: @Gas I think they are, I edited the question.

Comment: You are right, sorry. This plug-is uses MNESIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check the messages that RabbitMQ is persisting in it's mnesia database.

RabbitMQ is not a generalized datastore. It is a purpose-built message broker and queueing system. The datastore it has in it is there to facilitate the persistence of messages, not to be queried and used as if it were a database on it's own.

Comment: Generally yes, but this plug-in seems to use MNESIA to store messages.

Comment: as does all of RabbitMQ when storing messages on disk. that doesn't mean you get access to it. if you really wanted to, you probably could by using an mnesia library. i would highly recommend not doing that. if you need a database, use a database meant for your system.

Comment: using a simple erlang client it is possible to check the messages not delivered yet. Only for this plug-in.

Comment: @DerickBailey default RabbitMQ does not store messages on Mnesia at all. This plugin does. We have an issue that should allow users to inspect the delayed messages, or at least see how many there are: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

To view the data inside `MNESIA` you could :

1. Write a simple Erlang program as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763745/best-way-to-print-out-mnesia-table), as result you have:

> ```
>   (rabbit@gabrieles-MBP)5>
>     load:traverse_table_and_show('rabbit_delayed_messagerabbit@gabrieles-MBP').
>     {delay_entry,
>      {delay_key,1442258857832,
>              {exchange,
>                {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"my-exchange">>},
>                 'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
>                 [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"direct">>}],
>                 undefined,undefined,             {[],[]}}},
>          {delivery,false,false,<0.2008.0>,
>             {basic_message,
>                 {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"my-exchange">>},
>                  [<<>>],
>                 {content,60,
>                      {'P_basic',undefined,undefined,
>                          [{<<"x-delay">>,signedint,100000}],
>                          undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
>                         undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
>                        undefined},
>     ..
> ```

OR in this way:

1. execute an `Erlang` shell session using: 
   `erl -set-cookie ABCDEFGHI -sname monitorNode@gabrielesMBP`

   you have to use the same `cookie` that rabbitmq are using.

   Typically `$(HOME).erlang.cookie`

   2. execute this command:`observer:start().`
      and you should have this:

[image]

Once you are connected to `rabbitmq` node open Table Viewer and from the menu `Mnesia table` as:

[image]

Here you can see your data:

[image]